# Is an overheating motor on electric pressure washer ruined?

Tags: electric-motor, pressure-washer

The motor on my electric pressure washer started to smell yesterday after using it for 15 minutes.  I knew better, yet I continued to run it periodically for an additional 5-10 minutes over the next half hour.  It was still running and smelling when I finally stopped using it, but the spray pressure was low. Is the motor damaged?  For example, if the pump is the root problem and I fix the pump, will the motor still be able to drive the pump to put out the spec 1900 psi?

Comment: I'm not sure how we could know that with the information provided.

Comment: What additional information can I provide?

Comment: Well, it's really a matter of mechanical troubleshooting. That's a local task.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Seems my question is electrical, not mechanical. Given the smell, what can be inferred about the motor's condition?  I posit that the pump is failing and causing the motor to overheat.  If I rebuild/replace the pump, will the motor still be able to drive the pump to spec?

Comment: Motor failure is usually mechanical (worn brushes, burned windings, etc.). As you mentioned, a worn pump could also be the cause. Determining the answer to your question involves investigating that.

Comment: Isn't the obvious answer "probably"? I'm still not sure what else we can offer.

Comment: If it was a burnt smell, that might be the windings and the motor is shot.  Did the motor still seem to have full power or slowing down?

Comment: Based on 'motor hum', the motor seemed to be slowing down as if the pump was seizing, similar to table saw motor slowing down when I push stock too fast.

Comment: If the motor starts and runs without building pressure it is probably OK. If not you need to disconnect the pump and try again. If that works it would be the pump failing.

Comment: Given the range of great replies here, out of curiosity, I'll probably disassemble the PW.  But that would be much easier and quicker if I don't have to document how to put it back together should it be a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

What you smelled was burning insulation on the motor windings. This results in internal short circuits which only makes the problem worse and loss of power, the motor is hammered, done for, depleted, killed, fried, zero, zip, nada. My advice would be to toss the whole thing and buy a new one.

In the old days, electric motors could be repaired (the windings re-wound), but that's only cost effective now for large expensive, heavy duty motors.

Sorry to say, but its toast, IMHO,

Comment: That's what I'm resigned to at this point.

Comment: On the upside, it was a small fraction of the cost of a machine built with serviceable components.  So the logic is "why buy a repairable one, for that money I can just replace the non-repairable ones 3-4 times, and get a brand new machine everytime I do".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   Yeah, lots of "disposable" tools these days, it's a shame and a waste.   I have some tools from Sears (their Craftsman Commercial line) that I've had for 40+ years.   I still think Porter Cable and Milwaukee make decent tools that will last, others, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the motor started to smell, then it's insulation has started to melt. There's no way to determine how bad the insulation's been damaged. It could last for years or fail in a week. You could take it to a motor repair shop and get a megger test to determine the integrity of the insulation.

Comment: I can call a local alternator rebuild shop. How do I pronounce megger?  does iot rhyme with beggar or eager or ...?  What material is the insulation?  For example, I guess the melted insulation may have continued to insulate while melting, but not that the motor has cooled, the insulation has shrunk/cracked.

Comment: @user158587 It's begger with an "m". The insulation could be a red insulating varnish. It could start to melt and be weakened at certain points.

Comment: A megger can detect problems with insulation between the windings and the frame, but not between winding turns.  The insulation is called "enamel", but modern enamel is actually some type of plastic film.  Search "Magnet Wire" for more info.  Varnish might be applied after winding to better hold everything in place, but is often omitted to save cost